# HTML5 datalist does not open if input already focused

Tags: html, google-chrome

I came across this implementing "suggestions"-like lists on some number input fields;

If the input field is not active, clicking on the "down arrow" will open the drop-down list.

If the input field is already focused, click on the "down arrow" will flicker the drop-down list, but will not remain open and will close immediately.

```html
<input type="number" id="inputNumber" list="numberList">

<datalist id="numberList">
  <option value="2"/>
  <option value="3"/>
  <option value="5"/>
  <option value="7"/>
  <option value="11"/>
  <option value="13"/>
  <option value="17"/>
  <option value="54"/>
</datalist>
```

This happens with Google Chrome 44.0.2403.107. Is this a bug? Or is there something I don't understand?

** **Edit** **

Moreover, I just added the value `54` and the list *will* open if the value `5` is already set and the field is in focus, however *all* values will be shown. Clicking once more on the arrow will, then, filter out everything but `54` in the list. (**Note** that this is even inconsistent as the correct behaviour may also happen at times.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example actually works for me (Chrome 44.0.2403.157 m), although if the input box has a value for which there isn't an autocomplete suggestion for then no list will be shown.  I suppose this must be intended behaviour, although I agree it certainly isn't intuitive as clicking the arrow when the input isn't in focus will show the whole list regardless.

Comment: This happens for *any* value, less it is a portion of a value in the data list. For exemple, `6` is not in the data list, however the drop-down list *still* does not pop open when the field is already focused. This is an inconsistent behaviour that could be fixed quite easily by the Chrome devs.

Comment: I'll close this as it seems to be resolve with the latest Chrome.